# verilog code for priority encoder

Tags: verilog, digital-logic

I wrote verilog code for priority encoder, is this code ok for simulation purpose? What can be code for purpose of synthesis? Please give up your opinions and thoughts.

```
module pri_encoder(y,i,enable);
output reg [3:0]y;
input [15:0]i;
input enable;

always@(i or enable)
if(enable)
if(!i)
y=4'bx;
else if(i==1)
y=4'b0;
else if(i==2)
  y=1;
else if(i==3)
  y=2;
  else if(i>=4 && i<=7)
  y=3;
  else if(i>=8 && i<=16)
  y=4;
  else if(i>=16 && i<=32)
  y=5;
  else if(i>=32 && i<=64)
  y=6;
  else if(i>=64 && i<=128)
  y=7;
  else if(i>=128 && i<=256)
  y=8;
  else if(i>=256 && i<=512)
  y=9;
  else if(i>=512 && i<=1024)
  y=10;
  else if(i>=1024 && i<=2048)
  y=11;
endmodule
```

Comment: Your `if(enable)` in a combinatorial block will imply latches.

Answer (score 0):

The design you have is probably synthesizeable, but per the comment above, you will get a latch.  A casex statement might be more readable, provided you get rid of the latch.

Here is a small encoder I use.  I have modified it to have an enable.  It is critical to have the width of your "enable + select" input match the width of the vector in {1'b1,6'bxxxxxx}.  In this case 1 + 6 = 7.   You can enlarge to fit your need.

```
function [2:0] prienc6;
 input       enable;
 input [5:0] select;
 reg   [2:0] out;
 begin
   casex({enable,select})
     {1'b1,6'b000001}: out = 3'b101;
     {1'b1,6'b00001x}: out = 3'b100;
     {1'b1,6'b0001xx}: out = 3'b011; 
     {1'b1,6'b001xxx}: out = 3'b010; 
     {1'b1,6'b01xxxx}: out = 3'b001; 
     {1'b1,6'b1xxxxx}: out = 3'b000;
     {1'b0,6'bxxxxxx}: out = 3'b000;  // if you assign out = out, then you get latches.
   endcase

   prienc6 = out ;
 end
endfunction
```

You could expand this to include a prev_out, and a clock to avoid the latch, as such

```
reg [2:0] encode_out;

function [2:0] prienc6;
 input       enable;
 input [5:0] select;
 input [2:0] prev_out;
 reg   [2:0] out;
 begin
   casex({enable,select})
     {1'b1,6'b000001}: out = 3'b101;
     {1'b1,6'b00001x}: out = 3'b100;
     {1'b1,6'b0001xx}: out = 3'b011; 
     {1'b1,6'b001xxx}: out = 3'b010; 
     {1'b1,6'b01xxxx}: out = 3'b001; 
     {1'b1,6'b1xxxxx}: out = 3'b000;
     {1'b0,6'bxxxxxx}: out = prev_out;
   endcase

   prienc6 = out ;
 end
endfunction

always @ (posedge clk or posedge reset)
begin 
   if (reset) encode_out <= 3'b000;
   else encode_out <= prienc6(some_enable,some_select,encode_out); //latch avoided.

end
```

I don't know if this is suitable, but it is my preferred solution.  I make my enable external to the function.

```
reg [2:0] encode_out;

function [2:0] prienc6;
     input [5:0] select;
     reg   [2:0] out;
     begin
       casex(select)
         6'b000001: out = 3'b101;
         6'b00001x: out = 3'b100;
         6'b0001xx: out = 3'b011; 
         6'b001xxx: out = 3'b010; 
         6'b01xxxx: out = 3'b001; 
         6'b1xxxxx: out = 3'b000;
         default  : out = 3'b000;
       endcase

       prienc6 = out ;
     end
    endfunction

always @ (posedge clk or posedge reset)
begin 
   if (reset) encode_out <= 3'b000;
   else       encode_out <= enable ? prienc6(some_input) : encode_out;
end
```

Comment: Your `(enable,select)` is invalid syntax for a case statement, change it to the concatenated form: `({enable,select})`. Although legal, using `casex` is highly discouraged, use `casez` instead (and change the `x`s in the case conditions to `?`s). The reason for `casez` over `casex` is explained [here](http://www.verilogpro.com/verilog-case-casez-casex/) and [here](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG1999SJ_SynthMismatch.pdf) and verious other sources online when searching for _verilog casex vs casez_

Comment: Corrected the vector concantination.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is 3bit priority encoder. The same can be realized for your
code also. I have written the code in the simplest way possible.

Your code doesn't include the else condition which make the circuit to be synthesized into a latch.

```
module priority(input [7:0] a,
input enable,
output reg [2:0] b    );

always @(*)
begin
if(enable)
begin
if (a[7:0]==1)
b=0;
else if(a[7:1]==1)
b=1;
else if(a[7:2]==1)
b=2;
else if(a[7:3]==1)
b=3;
else if(a[7:4]==1)
b=4;
else if(a[7:5]==1)
b=5;
else if(a[7:6]==1)
b=6;
else if(a[7]==1)
b=7;
end
else
b=4'bxxxx;
end
endmodule
```

Comment: plz tell me which case will result in a latch?

Comment: Assume in the above program that there is no 'else'  command. If enable =1 then the if block wiil be executed and if  enable != 1 then the progarm has to wait till enable becomes 1 and has to store the previous output values. Storing of values can be done by using latches. @NavkantTyagi